# Wordpress - check if current user is logged as admin on non-wordpress scripts

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, cookies

i need my non-wordpress scripts to be able to get the current user infos (to check if he's an admin). To do this, i need to include this line in my scripts:

```
require_once('/home/anarchoi/public_html/blog/wp-load.php');
```

The problem is that the rest of my script is broken as soon as i add this line. If i comment it out, then everything will work.

Here's the rest of the script, just after the wp-load.php inclusion

```
$articleid = "test";
$lastviewedarticles = array();
$cookiedomain = ".ni-dieu-ni-maitre.com";

if (isset($_COOKIE["viewed_articles"]) ) {
  $lastviewedarticles = unserialize($_COOKIE["viewed_articles"]);
  if(!empty($_GET['debug'])) { 
  echo "cookie = $lastviewedarticles"; 
  print_r($lastviewedarticles);
  }
    if (is_array($lastviewedarticles) && !in_array($articleid, $lastviewedarticles)){  // is array pour éviter le bug msg erreur qui saffiche depuis qu'on intègre la liaison avec le wordpress admin check
        $count = count($lastviewedarticles);
        if($count>=50)
        array_shift($lastviewedarticles);
        $lastviewedarticles[] = $articleid;
    }
} else {
$lastviewedarticles[] = $articleid;
setcookie('viewed_articles', serialize($lastviewedarticles), time()+60*60*24*30, '/', $cookiedomain);
if(!empty($_GET['debug'])) { echo "cookie not set, setting $lastviewedarticles"; }
}
```

The first time the page is loaded, the cookie will be set, but everytime after that the script fails to get the content of the cookie.
If i check in my browsers cookies, i can find that the cookie IS here

I am also concerned about the speed impact of including wp-load.php in every pages of my website. Seems like a bit overkill just to check if an admin is logged on. AFAIK, wp-load.php will load the WHOLE wordpress scripts. Is there a better way to check if an admin is logged on, but OUTSIDE wordpress ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like wp-config.php might be the only include you need, as opposed to wp-load.php.

[There is a good discussion here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/check-for-login-outside-wordpress) about the same topic.

I have used the `get_currentuserinfo()` [function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo) in the past to check `$user_level` (should be 10 for admin) but I have not tried to do this OUTSIDE of WordPress.

Good luck!

Comment: i just tried that, exactly as described in the comments of your link, indeed it is an easier way to get the admin status, but i still have the same problem with the cookies :(